# hierachical mouse enter and mouse leave in APEX Oracle

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, event-propagation

I'm working with APEX Oracle ver 23.1.

I have an interactive grid including 1 column `ITEM1`. Each cell of column `ITEM1` include 3 values which can be displayed as following:

```js
$("*").on("mouseover", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("mouse_over");
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("*").on("mouseout", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("mouse_over");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#parent {
  padding: 24px;
  background-color:red;
}

.child {
  padding: 6px;
  background-color:white;
}

.mouse_over {
    background:url( data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAIUlEQVQYV2NkYGBIY2BgmMUABYxQGi4IEwCJgwWRBcCCAHscA2vMYjzKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
    ) repeat !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>Child 1 new</span>
   </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Child 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Child 3</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>Child 1.2</span>
  </td>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Child 2.2.2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Child 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to transfer this implementation to APEX Oracle.
I first create 2 dynamic actions: one when `Mouse Enter`, one when `Mouse Leave`. And TRUE action when `Mouse Enter` is copying value (`"child1, child2, child3"`) to clipboard. TRUE action when `Mouse Leave` is remove copying.

My problem is that

1. when moving the mouse from the parent to the child, the `Mouse Enter` DOES NOT fire for the child.
2. when moving the mouse back into the parent from the child, the `Mouse Enter` DOES NOT fire for the parent.

When adding `$(this.browserEvent.target).stopPropagation();` to both TRUE action, the copying function does not work.

What should I do in this case?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript code, you can access the text of the hovered element and copy it to the clipboard. You can use the document.execCommand('copy') method to copy the text to the clipboard. Here's an example code snippet:

```js
var target = $(this.triggeringElement);
var textToCopy = target.text().trim();

// Copy text to clipboard
var tempInput = $('<input>');
$('body').append(tempInput);
tempInput.val(textToCopy).select();
document.execCommand('copy');
tempInput.remove();
```

### Make sure to apply the appropriate event handling for your specific use case. This approach should work for most cases where you want to copy text to the clipboard when a user hovers over an element in Oracle APEX.
Dynamic Action for Mouse Leave:

Create another Dynamic Action for "Mouse Leave" on your interactive grid column ITEM1.
For the "When" condition, select "Mouse Leave" event.
For the "True Action," you can simply add a JavaScript code action to clear the clipboard if needed.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have appropriate javascript for copy to clipboard. My problem is when hovering between parent and child component, the action does not fire for corresponding level.

Comment: For example, on level of parent, I want to copy the whole value of cell. While on the level of child, I only want to copy that child value but not others in the same cell

Comment: does the event target is the parent or the child element ?

Comment: In my current implementation, there are: 1 dynamic action (DA) when mouse enter on parent, 1 DA when mouse leave on parent, 1 DA when mouse enter on child, 1 DA whe mouse leave on child. There are four DAs. 
Then the problem is when hovering mouse from child back to parent, the action of mouse enter does not fire and I cannot copy the whole value from parent level

Comment: try to use this:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hoverable").on("mouseover", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("mouse_over");
  });
 $(".hoverable").on("mouseout", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("mouse_over");
  });
});

Comment: In this code, you would need to add the "hoverable" class to the specific elements in your Oracle APEX application where you want this behavior to apply. This approach localizes the event handling to the elements you specify, making it more efficient and targeted.

Comment: Where should I put this?  Should it be next to `document.execCommand('copy');`

Comment: replace this :
$("*").on("mouseover", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("mouse_over");
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("*").on("mouseout", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("mouse_over");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
to that and tell me if it works for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255648/discussion-between-mohsin-iqbal-and-cassie).